# VScode Error"select an option to open remote window vs code"

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am a newbie and I guess this is a silly issue but appreciate your help here.

VSCode was running fine with no issues, but after creating a new virtual invironement to use Jupyter Notebook within vscode and successfully tested and running, vscode bottom left corner became orange and asking for "select an option to open remote window vs code" , what does that mean and how to fix it.

Note :I am just learning and running everything locally.

I want to understand why this changed , and how to fix it without connecting to remote stuff.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyfs3.png)